# Flutter trying to update (?) but not finding its repo

Tags: flutter

quite some while ago, I installed Flutter and played a bit with it. Now, some 6 months later, I want to try something else. Now, for every flutter command that I execute, flutter seems to clone a repository in `~/.flutter-sdk`.
For example, if I execute `flutter devices`, I get

```
Cloning into '/home/albert/.flutter-sdk'...
fatal: Remote branch alpha not found in upstream origin
```

I tried googling but I didn't find any solutions to this behaviour. Does someone know how to repair this?

Comment: you can try reinstalling flutter .

Comment: I tried reinstalling but I forgot to set the path (export PATH="$PATH:~/development/flutter/bin"). My old installation was still being used.